# What's the difference between python python3 and python3.7?

Tags: python, python3

I use these commands to show the Python versions and the result are here. What's the difference between them?

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.17
```

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
```

```
$ python3.7 --version
Python 3.7.5
```

Besides, what I want is minimal requirement Python 3.6 since I test VTA on Ubuntu, but get these errors.

```
$ python vta/tests/python/integration/test_benchmark_topi_conv2d.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vta/tests/python/integration/test_benchmark_topi_conv2d.py", line 27, in <module>
    import tvm
  File "/home/sophia/tvm/python/tvm/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from ._ffi.base import TVMError, __version__
  File "/home/sophia/tvm/python/tvm/_ffi/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import _pyversion
  File "/home/sophia/tvm/python/tvm/_ffi/_pyversion.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise Exception(PY3STATEMENT)
Exception: The minimal Python requirement is Python 3.6
```

Comment: Each release of Ubuntu has it's own versions of `python` it is built to utilize, the defaults should not be changed if you need Ubuntu tools to work as intended, you can see each version via https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python3  (likewise `python` where just remove the final 3 from package seach).  Python (2.7) stopped being a 'main' repo program in 19.04, being dropped 'universe' for 19.10 & renamed in *focal*.  What versions you get for `python -V; python3 -V` will vary depending on your release (you didn't specify)

Comment: I use ubuntu 18.04 LTS. `python -V` gave me  Python 2.7.17

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the call to the script like following

```
$ python3 vta/tests/python/integration/test_benchmark_topi_conv2d.py
```

You asked about the differences of the Python versions.

Python 3 is the successor to Python 2, and is not 100% compatible.

Not only has Python 3 new features, but also some Python 2 syntax is no more valid in Python 3.

Python uses semantic versioning, this means

- the first numbers "2" and "3" is the major version
- the second numbers "6" and "7" are minor versions, e.g. new features
- the third numbers "17", "9" and "5" are patches, ie bug fixes

Answer (score 0):

If you type `ll /usr/bin/python*` you will see symbolic links. In the example below, python points to python2, and python2 points to python2.7. These links may explain the difference between the versions.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Sep  4 00:49 /usr/bin/python -> python2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Sep  4 00:49 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7048 Aug 27 21:23 /usr/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1846 Aug 27 21:23 /usr/bin/python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Sep  4 00:49 /usr/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Sep  9 17:54 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.7
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 7048 Aug 27 22:02 /usr/bin/python3.7
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 7048 Aug 27 22:02 /usr/bin/python3.7m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 Sep  4 00:49 /usr/bin/python-config -> python2-config
```